# Is there a place where enemies always spawn on a roof?

Tags: infamous

There are some places in the city where enemies always spawn. Some examples include in the tunnel under the prison, right in front of the hospital, or on the plane wing sticking out of the trash town.

Is there such a spawn point that happens to place the enemies on top of a building somewhere?

Note that I've finished the game, so spawn points due to missions are obsolete. All missions are complete.

**Before you answer please remove all thoughts of stunts from your head. I want to know where enemies will ALWAYS spawn on a ROOF, regardless of your completion through the game. Nothing more, nothing less.**

Comment: Guessing you're going trophy hunting...?

Comment: yes indeed, lol. im 3 stunts away from the all stunts trophy (3 high falls simultaneous is the next one) and unknown amount of highfalls away from every 'kill this way' trophy. its becoming very fustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sevael Method:

> This works even if you have completely cleared Neon.
>
> Start by going up to Zeke's place. This will become your new respawn
>   point.
>
> Hop down onto the tracks just north of Zeke's building and head east
>   on the rails. Right up ahead is a train station. Head down to the
>   water just past the station. There is a broken dock in the water here
>   with a blast shard way out on the furthest pillar. You can grab the
>   shard at this point if you don't already have it.
>
> All you need to do is to jump out onto the first pillar of the broken
>   dock to trigger the upcoming Reaper spawn. Just glide out to the first
>   pillar, then turn around and glide back onto land. You'll notice that
>   when you turn around to face land again, a ton of people coming
>   running up to meet Cole (if your Karma is Hero).
>
> Head up the stairs to the train station up in front of you. As you run
>   up those stairs, five Reapers spawn on the platforms in the train
>   station. There will always be two on one side and three on the other,
>   and which side gets three is random.
>
> Get yourself over to the side with the three Reapers and kill the two
>   on the other side to keep them from shooting at you. If you have the
>   shield, now is a good time to use it. You can somewhat position the
>   Reapers by moving towards or away from them. Get them into either
>   stairwell, as this is your key choke point to hit all three with a
>   Shockwave blast.
>
> It's probably easiest to head down one of the stairways towards the
>   street and wait near the bottom. The three Reapers will join you on
>   the stairs and run back and forth while shooting at you. Keep your
>   shield up and wait for all three to stand in the same position. Since
>   you can't always see all three at once, just watch for the three red
>   marks on your mini-map to clump up. Once that happens, immediately run
>   up to them and use Shockwave. If you can keep your view pointed
>   slighting upwards, this increases your odds.
>
> If it went well, you will get the Have A Nice Fall stunt. If you
>   failed, just jump into the water and you'll immediately respawn at
>   Zeke's. Hop down to the tracks and head back to the train station and
>   try again.

I've used this and it works. There are some possible quirks. Here is a link to an archived thread discussing this method: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/942025-infamous/49726407

Here is an embedded video to help visualize this method:

Comment: Wow. Well written, however, I don't always, (in fact I almost never) seem to get the 'Have a Nice Fall' from train-track kills. And the question specifically mentioned a roof.

Comment: It takes some work and luck, but I personally was in the same boat as you and this is a pretty solid method for that achievement. It would be great if a reliable roof location existed for this during endgame, but during my initial research and this refresher I couldn't find one. Best of Luck.

Comment: I dont need the acheivement. I have it. The question isn't how to get the acheivement, its if there is a roof spawnpoint.

Comment: There is not a consistent roof spawn point during end-game.

Comment: can you provide some sort of source to that? if so, post it as an answer and I'll accept. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can. I've played the game to death getting my platinum, and have googled, researched, and personally looked.  Nothing I've found suggests there is a ALWAYS SPAWN location. With my answer and following comments, I intended to solve what I thought was the true question: Getting achievements in end-game.  I realize this isn't what you were looking for, but I will leave this answer up to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck hunting for this trophy too. It's a real pain.

[PS3 Trophies](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/infamous/14386-infamous-stunt-list-guide.html) lists good locations to get each stunt. You're after:

> - Have A Nice Fall - Kill 3 enemies at once by making them fall from a high place. This stunt will require some practice as well. I got this
>     stunt in Neon during the mission that you have to destroy the Reapers
>     Tar injectors on the roofs of buildings. There will be a lot of
>     enemies on these roofs. You need to wait until there is a group of
>     enemies standing together in close proximity to each other then u need
>     to shockwave the group off the roof. I used the shockwave on the good
>     side because it throws enemies farther. There are other spots to
>     accomplish this stunt but this was the easiest for me. Just make sure
>     you get all 3 enemies with one shockwave.

If you've missed the best places as listed, you could start a new game to reach those destinations (there are both sets of good and bad trophies to collect after all).

Comment: Note that if you start a new game, you do have to do all your stunts over again, so if you had a ton of trouble with one BESIDES this it may not be the best option for you, especially if you've already done two playthroughs.

Comment: yea see. im trying to avoid yet ANOTHER playthrough because then ill have to redo the stunt where you throw their grenade back at them. that ones practically freakin impossible as they only throw grenades every 5 minutes at best. i need a spawn point that doesnt involve any missions.

Comment: Good point @Shinrai.